# Recursively print in scala

Tags: scala, recursion

I have just picked up Scala like 2 hours ago, and I am thinking of printing a series like 1 to 10 but in a recursive fashion. I do not understand what is wrong with this:

```
def printSeries(x:Int):Int = {
  if(x==0) doNothing() else doSomething()

  def doNothing()  = {}

  def doSomething() = {
    println(x)
    printSeries(x-1)
  }

}
```

Sorry, this might be very basic. Please point out my mistakes or any alternative and simpler implementation. (I do not want to use loops).

Thanks,

Comment: Unrelated but maybe of interest to you, Coursera just started a class on Scala last week taught by Martin Odersky (the creator of Scala): [link](https://class.coursera.org/progfun-002/auth/welcome)

Comment: ^ And I just finished the lecture videos for Week 2. Such an awesome instructor he is.

Comment: Thanks Nathan for the coursera link. Will definitely check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you are promising to return Int from `printSeries`. Why? If method is printing, isn't much more natural* to make it return Unit (aka void). This is usually can be done either explicitly

```
def printSeries(upTo: Int): Unit = { .... }
```

or implicitly:

```
def printSeries(upTo: Int) { .... }
```

(see, no equals sign in code above).

Next, why do you have explicit doNothing method? I think it would be better to write something like:

```
def printSeries(upTo: Int) {
  if(upTo > 0) {
    println(upTo)
    printSeries(upTo - 1)
  }
}
```

You also might want to place @tailrec annotation to ensure that code will be optimized and won't fail with Stackoverflow at big `upTo` numbers (if it will and function is annotated compiler will yell on you).

```
@annotation.tailrec
def printSeries(upTo: Int) {
  if(upTo > 0) {
    println(upTo)
    printSeries(upTo - 1)
  }
}
```

Finally, generally, it is better to produce sequences and only then make something with them.

P.S. you might better to post questions like this on [code review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not on stackoverlow itself

* there is a good rule in programming to make functions *do one thing and be good at it* so getXandMakeY usually is bad idea.

Comment: Thanks @om-nom-nom, I did not know about Unit. Also thanks for the code review web site link. I did not know about that.

Answer (score 1):

Because your method signature is `Int => Int`, your method expects to return an Int. You might have wanted to define it like `def printSeries(x:Int):Unit = {` sot that it does not need to return something.

Besides, you can do it with the following shorter function

```
def printSeries(x:Int):Unit= {
  if(x>0) {
    println(x)
    printSeries(x-1)
  }
}
```

Other alternatives using val and pattern matching at the same time.

```
val printSeries: (Int)=> Unit = _ match {
   case x if x>0 =>
     println(x)
     printSeries(x-1)
   case _ =>
}
```

Another alternative using anonymous function

```
val printSeries: (Int)=> Unit = { x =>
   if(x>0) {
     println(x)
     printSeries(x-1)
   }
}
```

Comment: I think pattern matching here is kinda harmfull.

Comment: Because it concerns integers, yes, But this can be generalized for other cases.

Comment: [...can be generalized for other cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI)